systemd-cryptenroll for LUKS volume with detached header
I have encrypted LUKS volume with detached header and I want to open it using TPM. Problem is systemd-cryptenroll doesn't have option for detached header. Is it possible to overcome this or perform "enroll" manually?

Does such a combination even make sense? My impression was that detached headers were mostly in use in situations where one didn't want any form of unattended unlock?

I like and use detached header because such disk can be made unencrypted by overriding raw disk with decrypted data using dd without any further problems with disk size. But main reason: it is logical for me, as disk stores only encrypted data, header is stored elsewhere and can be easily erased or backed up.

cryptenroll can be executed on header itself
systemd-cryptenroll --tpm2-device=auto /boot/header.img

If that didn't work you can try:
Use luksOpen to open partition
cryptsetup -q luksOpen "${Files_partition}" "${Map}" --header "${Header}"

Create hash of the unencrypted data for later use
dd if=/dev/mapper/"${Map}" bs=4M count=100 | sha256sum

Close LUKS partition
cryptsetup luksClose $Map

Create virtual device from header
losetup /dev/loop100 "${Header}"

Virtually join header and encrypted data device using RAID
mdadm --build /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/loop100 "${Files_partition}"

luksOpen will not work because data offset is 0 yet header virtually not detached. Enroll TPM
systemd-cryptenroll --tpm2-device=auto /dev/md0

Finish this non-sense
mdadm  --stop /dev/md0
losetup -d /dev/loop100

After that
cryptsetup -q luksOpen "${Files_partition}" "${Map}" --header "${Header}"

didn't ask a password.
Verify data
dd if=/dev/mapper/"${Map}" bs=4M count=100 | sha256sum

For me hash is the same. You can create hash for whole device if you want to be sure.
